# Can I calculate the amount (mol, mass) of water in a gas, in a heat exchanger, if I know the partial pressure of the water?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, water, ideal-gas

Is it possible to calculate the amount of water (mol, mass...) in a gas, in a heat exchanger (open system) if I know the partial pressure of the water? The stream through the tubes is mainly benzene and hydrocarbons.

I first tried to use the ideal gas law with the compressibility factor, but that equation is meant for closed systems (like in a tank) and not open systems like the one described. (If I'm wrong and it can be used, give me a good reason why).

If you have any more questions, please ask.

Edit: partial pressure of the water and the temperature is constant

Comment: Is the partial pressure of the water vapor and the temperature constant?  If so, then you can use the ideal gas law (over the volume of gas in the tubes).

Comment: The gas laws are not confined to open or closed systems. A gas does not behave differently (i.e. the model has to change) just because the system is open or closed. You may be confused that you should use molar volume rather than moles and volume separately. Finally, this may be a question to ask in the engineering stack rather than here in the physics stack.